# Tensorflow - synchronize readings from tfrecord

Tags: tensorflow

I'm a bit new to tensorflow and I'm trying to create an input pipeline based on tfrecord file. Each entry in the file contains three field: 2 strings with paths to 2 image file and 1 float tensor (the labels for the example). I'm able to write and read back again the information, unfortunately I have some problem keeping image and labels synchronized.

To save the records I'm using this piece of code

```
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_tfrecord)
...
for index in shuffled_indexes:
   example = tf.train.Example(
              features=tf.train.Features(
              feature={
                'label': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=target.ravel().tolist()),
                'image_1': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[image_1.encode()])),
                'image_2': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[image_2.encode()]))
              }
        )
    )
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()
```

And to read it back again this one (for this example I'm ignoring field 'image_2' in each record):

```
def read_and_decode(filename, target_shape):
# first construct a queue containing a list of filenames.
# this lets a user split up there dataset in multiple files to keep
# size down
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename,num_epochs=None)

#symbolic reader to read one example at a time
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
features = tf.parse_single_example(
    serialized_example,
    # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
    features={
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature(target_shape, tf.float32),
        'image_1': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'image_2': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    }
)

img_filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([features['image_1']],shuffle=False)
image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
_, image_file = image_reader.read(img_filename_queue)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file, channels=3)
with tf.control_dependencies([image]):
    label = features['label']


return image,label
```

Each couple image and label are an example from my training set. If I try to run them in a single session what I get are not synchronized result, e.g. in a toy example with just two records in the tfrecord file the image and label are exchanged: first label with second image and vice versa.

Example of my session code:

```
image,label = read_and_decode([outputfileName],result_shape)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Start the queue runners (input threads)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    for i in range(2):
        img,trg = sess.run([image,label])
        ioUtils.visualizeLabel(img,trg)

# When done, ask the threads to stop.
coord.request_stop()
# Wait for threads to finish.
coord.join(threads)
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, the problem was in

```
img_filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([features['image_1']],shuffle=False)
```

the string_input_producer was messing up with the rest of the piepline. The proper way to write read_and_decode is

```
def read_and_decode_tfrecord(filename, target_shape):
# first construct a queue containing a list of filenames.
# this lets a user split up there dataset in multiple files to keep
# size down
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename,num_epochs=None)

#symbolic reader to read one example at a time
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
features = tf.parse_single_example(
    serialized_example,
    # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
    features={
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature(target_shape, tf.float32),
        'image_1': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'image_2': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    }
)

image_file = tf.read_file(image_path_1)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file, channels=3)
with tf.control_dependencies([image]):
    label = features['label']

return image,label
```