# Tensorflow: Modern way to load large data

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, tfrecord

I want to train a convolutional neural network (using tf.keras from Tensorflow version 1.13) using numpy arrays as input data. The training data (which I currently store in a single >30GB '.npz' file) does not fit in RAM all at once. **What is the best way to save and load large data-sets into a neural network for training?** Since I didn't manage to find a good answer to this (surely ubiquitous?) problem, I'm hoping to hear one here. Thank you very much in advance for any help!

#### Sources

Similar questions seem to have been asked many times (e.g. [training-classifier-from-tfrecords-in-tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169016/training-classifier-from-tfrecords-in-tensorflow), [tensorflow-synchronize-readings-from-tfrecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467990/tensorflow-synchronize-readings-from-tfrecord), [how-to-load-data-parallelly-in-tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51357223/how-to-load-data-parallelly-in-tensorflow)) but are several years old and usually contain no conclusive answer.

My current understanding is that using TFRecord files is a good way to approach this problem. The most promising tutorial I found so far explaining how to use TFRecord files with keras is [medium.com](https://medium.com/@moritzkrger/speeding-up-keras-with-tfrecord-datasets-5464f9836c36). Other helpful sources were [machinelearninguru.com](http://machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/data_preparation/tfrecord/tfrecord.html) and [medium.com_source2](https://medium.com/mostly-ai/tensorflow-records-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them-c46bc4bbb564) and sources therin.

The official tensorflow documentation and tutorials (on [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset), [Importing Data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets), [tf_records](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tf_records) etc.) did not help me. In particular, several of the examples given there didn't work for me even without modifications.

#### My Attempt at using TFRecord files

I'm assuming TFRecords are a good way to solve my problem but I'm having a hard time using them. Here is an example I made based on the tutorial [medium.com](https://medium.com/@moritzkrger/speeding-up-keras-with-tfrecord-datasets-5464f9836c36). I stripped down the code as much as I could.

```
# python 3.6, tensorflow 1.13.
# Adapted from https://medium.com/@moritzkrger/speeding-up-keras-with-tfrecord-datasets-5464f9836c36
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python import keras as keras


# Helper functions (see also https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tf_records)
def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


def writeTFRecords():
    number_of_samples = 100  # create some random data to play with
    images, labels = (np.random.sample((number_of_samples, 256, 256, 1)), np.random.randint(0, 30, number_of_samples))

    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter("bla.tfrecord")

    for index in range(images.shape[0]):
        image = images[index]
        label = labels[index]

        feature = {'image':  _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(image.tostring())),
                   'label':  _int64_feature(int(label))}

        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()


def loadTFRecord(data_path):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        feature = {'train/image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                   'train/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}
        # Create a list of filenames and pass it to a queue
        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([data_path], num_epochs=1)
        # Define a reader and read the next record
        reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
        _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
        # Decode the record read by the reader
        features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feature)
        # Convert the image data from string back to the numbers
        image = tf.decode_raw(features['train/image'], tf.float32)

        # Cast label data into int32
        label = tf.cast(features['train/label'], tf.int32)
        # Reshape image data into the original shape
        image = tf.reshape(image, [256, 256, 1])

        return image, label  # I'm not 100% sure that's how this works...


# ######### generate a TFRecords file in the working directory containing random data. #################################
writeTFRecords()
# ######## Load the TFRecords file and use it to train a simple example neural network. ################################
image, label = loadTFRecord("bla.tfrecord")

model_input = keras.layers.Input(tensor=image)
model_output = keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(-1, 256, 256, 1))(model_input)
model_output = keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(model_output)

train_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=model_output)
train_model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001),  
                    loss='mean_squared_error',
                    target_tensors=[label])

print("\n \n start training \n \n") # Execution gets stuck on fitting
train_model.fit(epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=10)  # no output or error messages.
```

The code creates a TFRecord file and starts fitting, then just gets stuck with no output or error messages. I don't know what the problem is or how I could try to fix it.

Comment: I haven't used TF for a long time, so I'll add a comment. Take a look at TF's batching/pipelining/ETL (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets). Apparently the dataset provides small enough batches for TF's graph to run on, and prefetch data from disk in the background.

Comment: No solutions for this yet?

Comment: @Vimieiro I posted an answer showing a minimal example of the method (TFRecord files and tensorflow datasets) that I ended up using for the project at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is no real answer to the original question (i.e. "what is the optimal way to train on large datasets"), I managed to get tfrecords and datasets to work. Of particular help was this [tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxrcZ9uUblI&list=PL9Hr9sNUjfsmEu1ZniY0XpHSzl5uihcXZ&index=25). I include a minimal example with working code for anyone struggling with the same problem.

```
# Developed using python 3.6, tensorflow 1.14.0.
# This code writes data (pairs (label, image) where label is int64 and image is np.ndarray) into .tfrecord files and
# uses them for training a simple neural network. It is meant as a minimal working example of how to use tfrecords. This
# solution is likely not optimal. If you know how to improve it, please comment on
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/57717004/9988487. Refer to links therein for further information.
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python import keras as keras


# Helper functions (see also https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tf_records)
def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


def write_tfrecords_file(out_path: str, images: np.ndarray, labels: np.ndarray) -> None:
    """Write all image-label pairs into a single .tfrecord file.
    :param out_path: File path of the .tfrecord file to generate or overwrite.
    :param images: array with first dimension being the image index. Every images[i].tostring() is
        serialized and written into the file as 'image': wrap_bytes(img_bytes)
    :param labels: 1d array of integers. labels[i] is the label of images[i]. Written as 'label': wrap_int64(label)"""
    assert len(images) == len(labels)
    with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(out_path) as writer:  # could use writer_options parameter to enable compression
        for i in range(len(labels)):
            img_bytes = images[i].tostring()  # Convert the image to raw bytes.
            label = labels[i]
            data = {'image': _bytes_feature(img_bytes), 'label': _int64_feature(label)}
            feature = tf.train.Features(feature=data)  # Wrap the data as TensorFlow Features.
            example = tf.train.Example(features=feature)  # Wrap again as a TensorFlow Example.
            serialized = example.SerializeToString()  # Serialize the data.
            writer.write(serialized)  # Write the serialized data to the TFRecords file.


def parse_example(serialized, shape=(256, 256, 1)):
    features = {'image': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string), 'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}
    # Parse the serialized data so we get a dict with our data.
    parsed_example = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized=serialized, features=features)
    label = parsed_example['label']
    image_raw = parsed_example['image']  # Get the image as raw bytes.
    image = tf.decode_raw(image_raw, tf.float32)  # Decode the raw bytes so it becomes a tensor with type.
    image = tf.reshape(image, shape=shape)
    return image, label  # this function will be called once (to add it to tf graph; then parse images individually)


# create some arbitrary data to play with: 1000 images sized 256x256 with one colour channel. Use your custom np-arrays
IMAGE_WIDTH, NUM_OF_IMAGES, NUM_OF_CLASSES, COLOUR_CHANNELS = 256, 10_000, 10, 1
# using float32 to save memory. Must match type in parse_example(), tf.decode_raw(image_raw, tf.float32)
features_train = np.random.sample((NUM_OF_IMAGES, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_WIDTH, COLOUR_CHANNELS)).astype(np.float32)
labels_train = np.random.randint(low=0, high=NUM_OF_CLASSES, size=NUM_OF_IMAGES)  # one random label for each image
features_eval = features_train[:200]  # use the first 200 images as evaluation data for simplicity.
labels_eval = labels_train[:200]
write_tfrecords_file("train.tfrecord", features_train, labels_train)  # normal: split the data files of several GB each
write_tfrecords_file("eval.tfrecord", features_eval, labels_eval)  # this may take a while. Consider a progressbar
# The files are complete. Now define a model and use datasets to feed the data from the .tfrecord files into the model.
model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(256, 256, 1)),
                          keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
                          keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
# Check docs for parameters (compression, buffer size, thread count. Also www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets

train_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("train.tfrecord")  # specify a list (or dataset) of file names for large data
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(parse_example)  # parse tfrecords. Parameter num_parallel_calls may help performance.
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(64)

validation_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("eval.tfrecord")
validation_dataset = validation_dataset.map(parse_example).batch(64)

model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=3)
# evaluate the results
results = model.evaluate(validation_dataset)
print('\n\nvalidation loss, validation acc:', results)
```

Note that it's tricky to use some_keras_model.fit(..., validation_data=some_dataset) with dataset objects. It may result in
`TypeError: 'DatasetV1Adapter' object does not support indexing`.
This seems to be a bug (see github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28995) and is supposedly fixed as of  tf-nightly version '1.15.0-dev20190808'; The [official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate) uses this too, although it doesn't work in most versions. An easy but dirty-ish fix is to use verbose=0 (which only suppresses program output) and plot the validation results using tensorboard. Also see [Keras model.fit() with tf.dataset API + validation_data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50955798/keras-model-fit-with-tf-dataset-api-validation-data#50979587).